# calculator error in C

Tags: c, types, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator program in C. I've done most of the it i think...just that the output is incorrect. The output that is supposed to come out doesn't. below is the code the calculator program!.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add(double num1,double num2);
void del(double num1,double num2);
void mul(double num1,double num2);
void divide(double num1,double num2);
main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char sym;
    float num1, num2;
    int ret;
    fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fscanf(fp,"%f%c%f", &num1,&sym,&num2)!=EOF){
        switch(sym){
            case '+': add(num1,num2);
                    break;
            case '-': del(num1,num2);
                    break;
            case '*': mul(num1,num2);
                    break;
            case '/': divide(num1,num2);
                    break;
            default: printf("%f%c%f", num1,sym,num2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void add(double num1,double num2){
    double result;
    result = num1+num2;
    printf("%f\n", result);
}

void del(double num1,double num2){
    double result;
    result = num1-num2;
    printf("%f\n", result);
}

void mul(double num1,double num2){
    double result;
    result = num1*num2;
    printf("%f\n", result);
}

void divide(double num1,double num2){
    double result;
    result = num1/num2;
    printf("%f\n", result);
}
```

when i have inputs of:

```
123456789+987654321
123456789-987654321
12345*54321
1349.238912+12384.12871
3918.381631-1287.38272
```

The results I'm supposed to get are the following:

```
1111111110.000000
-864197532.000000
670592745.000000
13733.367622
2090.998911
```

but these are the results I actually get:

```
1111111128.000000
-864197544.000000
670592745.000000
13733.367798
2090.998901
```

and I'm not even sure why the middle operation works well when the rest doesn't
I've tried using float as my data type for `num1` and `num2`, but the results were far more off than using double.

Comment: As a side note, each of your functions could resolve to one line. (i.e. printf("%f\n", num1+num2); ). Alternatively you could even put those one-liners in your switch-case.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Last week's course home works seems to be calculators and reading/printing character tuples ... ;-)

Comment: @sherrellbc what do you mean by putting them in my switch-case?

Comment: @user3121023 nope T.T outputs go crazy off the charts

Comment: oh sorry.... i had types for num1 and num2 on float.. :D

Comment: Does it work for smaller numbers like, `.1`, `1.`, `10.`, `100.`?

Comment: @user3121023: `%lf` isn't a valid format specifier for `printf`. The specifier for `double` is `%f` (and for `long double` it's `%Lf`). For `scanf`, it's `%f` for float and `%lf` for double, though.

Comment: @mafso: That might be true for `printf`, but there is a distinction between `%f` and `%lf` in `scanf`; they require pointers to `float` and `double` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question in the comments about what I said regarding streamlining the program, consider the following code:

*Note that I also included revisions to the code reflecting the original problem. Namely, you were using a `float` data type that was being implicitly cast to `double` followed by a printf() call with `float` specifiers.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char sym;
    double num1, num2;

    fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL)
        exit(1);

    while( fscanf(fp,"%f%c%f", &num1,&sym,&num2) != EOF )
        switch(sym){
            case '+':
                    printf("%f\n", num1+num2);
                    break;
            case '-': 
                    printf("%f\n", num1-num2);
                    break;
            case '*':
                    printf("%f\n", num1*num2);
                    break;
            case '/': 
                    printf("%f\n", num1/num2);
                    break;
            default: 
                    printf("%f%c%f", num1,sym,num2);
        }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Notice the reduced brackets as well. You are only required to include brackets for statements that have multiple statements that depend on it.

As in:

```
if(myVar == 1){
    printSomething();
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

However, if you only require one statement then you can drop the brackets.

```
if(myVar == 1)
    printSomething();
```

Note that if you have a single `block` of code that follows you still can drop the brackets (as is the same with your code above - the while loop has only a single switch-case).

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but this is not an answer to the original question. I think downvoting is a bit harsh so I won't, but you might want to also address the real question.

Comment: It was just must simpler to answer here than type out what I meant in the comments. The answer has already been addressed - he was using float type and then implicitly casting to double and then using float specifiers.

Comment: I agree, that is why I did not downvote, but it would be great if you could include the answer in the comments in this answer, so that it is more visible

Comment: Fair enough and I appreciate the comment. Thanks for the down-vote refrain.